# Обучаюсь по djangogirls. Нарвался на ошибку

Tags: django

Здравствуйте. Изучаю Django по djangogirls. Нарвался на ошибку.
Застрял на разделе [Django ORM](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/django_orm/).

> Все просто: мы импортируем модель Post из blog.models. Давай попробуем
>   получить все записи блога еще раз:
>
> ```
> >>>Post.objects.all() 
> [<Post: my post title>, <Post: another post title>]
> ```

а у меня:

```
Post.objects.all() 
[]
```

... и далее ниже ошибка:

```
    >>> me = User.objects.get(username='ola')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/loma/djanjogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/loma/djanjogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 387, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

git - http://goo.gl/Z0yZj3

Comment: В чем заключается ошибка? Я вижу пустой массив.

Comment: Пустой список говорит о том, что в таблице нет ни одной записи. Просто их надо создать.

Comment: @Invision добавил ерор ниже

Comment: @МистерФикс Как? (myvenv) ~/djangogirls$ python manage.py makemigrations blog (myvenv) ~/djangogirls$ python manage.py migrate blog не помогло

Answer (score 4):

Пустой список говорит о том, что в таблице нет ни одной записи. Просто их надо создать.

Способы создания:

```
p = Post(autor=user, title="заголовок", text="текст")
p.save()

p = Post.objects.create(autor=user, title="заголовок", text="текст")
```

После этого при выборке список будет с результатами.

Первым пользователем лучше создать суперпользователя из коммандной строки. Заходим в папку с файлом `manage.py` и пишем `manage.py createsuperuser`

Comment: Я так и делаю далее по туториалу - http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/django_orm/   
`Post.objects.create(author=me, title='Sample title', text='Test')`  
`>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User`  
`>>> User.objects.all()`  
`me = User.objects.get(username='ola')`   И далее error выше - django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.

Comment: Это невозможно, потому как ошибка DoesNotExist при попытке найти пользователя, означает, что такой записи не найдено. А если её не найдено, то значит её и нету. Посмотрите сначала есть ли в базе ваши модели, потому как в обоих запросах джанго ничего не находит.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по описанию проблемы, вы не сделали миграции для дефолтных таблиц проекта. Повторите создание миграций без аргументов

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```